# Change TabBarController in detail view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

So I have a TabBarController with 2 views. One of the views is a TableView in navigationController. When user selects a row I push a detail view there.
I want this detail view to have its own TabBarController different from the former one.

So basically the question is if I can push a view on top different view with different TabBarController, but using navigationController not as a modal view.

well.. I got 2 root views (items, global statistics).. and I switch between them using tabBarController..
once user click on item in 'items' view --> navigation push detailed item statistics.. problem is these statistics are divided into 2 sections and I need 2 views for them.
so

```
item table view
    - detailed view
        -detailed view 1
        -detailed view 2
global stats view
```

Answer (score 0):

the frame of the nav controller doesn't include the tab bar. the tab bar is used to switch between parallel modes, which doesn't seem to be what you're using it for, so it designed to be at the top of the hierarchy.  so you want something pinned at the bottom of the tableview that gives options right?
you might want to change the frame of the table view and add whatever buttons you want below it.